# Hibernate 2nd level cache configuration not working with spring xml, as there is no hibernate specific xml in the application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

> Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given, please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory class name to property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class (and make sure the second level cache provider, hibernate-infinispan, for example, is available in the classpath).

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
         <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  
         <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.genpact.cards.services.database"/>
         <property name="hibernateProperties">  
             <props>  
                  <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>  
                  <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>  
                  <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>  
                  <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                  <prop key="connection.pool_size">1</prop>
                  <prop key="maxActive">1</prop>
                  <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
                  <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                  <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
                  <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache}</prop>  


                  <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">/ehcache.xml</prop>
              </props>  
          </property>  
    </bean>
```

Comment: Do you have the hibernate-ehcache dependency in your classpath?

Comment: And the `SessionFactory` you are using is the spring configured session factory? YOu don't have another factory/util class that tries to creaet a `SessionFactory`. Or in short, post the full stacktrace.

Comment: hibernate-ehcache dependency ia there in the pom.xml